# Username in Profile for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using RoR 2.3.8. I have the following codes:

**user.rb**

```
def to_param
  "#{login.downcase.gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/,'-')}".gsub(/-{2,}/,'-')
end
```

**people_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @person = User.find(params[:id])

  if current_user == @person
    @posts = @person.posts.paginate(:page => params[:page], :order => order)
  else
    @posts = @person.posts.by_status('published').paginate(:page => params[:page], :order => order)
  end
end
```

I have a column `login` in `Users` database where unique username is. `People` is just a controller to show some posts created by the user.

I will usually link to the `index.html.erb` under my `people` controller with the url `http://localhost:3000/people/2` with the following code example in User's posts:

```
<a href="<%= person_path(@post.user.id) %>"><%=h @post.user_name %></a>
```

I want the URL to be `http://localhost:3000/people/victor` where `victor` is the `login` for a user. This url should also actually show the profile `show.html.erb` in `people` controller.

What else do I need to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use the [friendly_ID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem for this sort of thing - it's very straightforward - good luck

Answer (score 0):

I would modify routes.rb, something like this:

```
match 'people/:login' => 'people#show', :as => 'login'
```

And then modify a people_controller.rb:

```
def show
  @person = User.where(:login => params[:login]).first
end
```

*edited after additional information*
*corrected error*

Comment: The user_name is only used in User's posts. Post.rb

Comment: @Victor - so there is also a login field in User model, right? I'll fix the code then

Comment: @Nikita - I used this `map.person '/:login', :controller => 'people', :action => 'show'` as I am using Rails 2.3.8. I got this problem: `Couldn't find User without an ID`

Comment: @Victor - I made a mistake in my code. `login` is not a primary key in table users, so you should use `User.where` method. Since this method returns an array, but login is unique, it is OK to get the user with method `first`. I fixed code in my answer.

Comment: @nikita..you can use `User.find_by_login(params[:login])`

Comment: @Nikita - I am sorry that I didn't include the rest of the code in `people_controller.rb` which finds the posts from user by ID. So with @rubyprince method, it returns the error: `undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass`.